# Node.js cluster passing connection to specific worker

Tags: node.js, multithreading, socket.io

I have my multiplayer game based on socket.io library and i want to scale it on multiple threads. I've learned that node.js have cluster module to handle multithreading. 
My game world is made of multiple zones and I want each zone to be handled in it's own proccess. I need a method to pass user's socket to specific worker, so user could move from zone to zone. 
I've read in node.js docs that cluster module uses round-robin method to pick worker for every connection. Maybe there is any workaround to manipulate connections?

Comment: you could get creative and start the processes and communicate to them via a queue of some sort, such as 0mq.  Its not what you are looking for as an answer, but it could be a fall back

Comment: Hi @akaphenom, thank you for your answer. I've never heard of zmq before. Maybe you have any links on how to deal with similar situations using zmq and node.js?

Comment: I think that you can solve this just by using a webserver like `nginx` or `HAProxy`. You can launch multiple instances of same application on each server using `Docker` then use either `nginx` or `HAProxy` to load balance it.

Comment: @Gugis how did you approach this? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure that clustering is the right solution for you.  The main advantage of clustering is that it does automatic balancing of the incoming connections among the different processes.  But, you don't want to use that capability - you want to manually assign each connection to the process that is handling a given zone.

As such, I'm thinking that you should just start up the number of processes you want, assign them each a port that is specific to that zone and then have the client send an Ajax request to the master asking what port should they do a socket.io connection to for their zone.  The client gets that ajax response and then connects directly to the appropriate server for their zone.  All your socket.io servers would need to allow cross-origin requests from the desired master page domain/port.

Connecting to the server for a zone could either be done via port as described above or it could be done via a separate hostname such as `zone1.mygameserver.com` and then use something like nginx to route all the different hosts to specific ports on your server box.

Comment: So when user wants to exit one zone and enter another client should disconnect from current zone server and connect to new zone? But what if transition between zones must be imperceptible, without loading screen and etc?

Comment: @Gugis - You're talking about a socket.io connection.   Closing one socket.io connection and opening another has no effect at all on the user's screen or the current page or anything, it's completely invisible to the user.

Comment: But how can I transfer session safely?

Comment: @Gugis - I don't know how to transfer a socket from one clustered process to another.  My answer was suggesting a way where you don't have to transfer it.  Your master tells the client which zone server to directly connect to.  And, if it wants to change zones, the server can just send it a message to tell it to reconnect to a new zone.  Just creating a new connection to the new zone should be no big deal.